# How can I prohibit the submission of a form under certain conditions? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have a feedback form with a rating for the institution.
How can I prohibit the submission of the form if the rating is not selected and there are less than 10 characters in the comment?

```
<form class="form" action="">
    <div class="rating">
        <input class="star" type="radio" id="star-1" name="rating" value="1">
        <label for="star-1" title="Rating «1»"></label>
      
        <input class="star" type="radio" id="star-2" name="rating" value="2">
        <label for="star-2" title="Rating «2»"></label>
      
        <input class="star" type="radio" id="star-3" name="rating" value="3">
        <label for="star-3" title="Rating «3»"></label>
      
        <input class="star" type="radio" id="star-4" name="rating" value="4">
        <label for="star-4" title="Rating «4»></label>
      
        <input class="star" type="radio" id="star-5" name="rating" value="5">
        <label for="star-5" title="Rating «5»"></label>
      
      </div>
      <input class="comment" type="textarea" class="text" name="text">
     <button class="button">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan to do any custom validation, you can use the inbuilt [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation).

In this case:

- We add a `required` attribute to one of the radios to make them required.
- We add `required` to the comment and `minLength="10"` to specify that constraint

```html
<form class="form" action="">
    <div class="rating">
        <input class="star" type="radio" id="star-1" name="rating" value="1" required>
        <label for="star-1" title="Rating «1»"></label>
      
        <input class="star" type="radio" id="star-2" name="rating" value="2">
        <label for="star-2" title="Rating «2»"></label>
      
        <input class="star" type="radio" id="star-3" name="rating" value="3">
        <label for="star-3" title="Rating «3»"></label>
      
        <input class="star" type="radio" id="star-4" name="rating" value="4">
        <label for="star-4" title="Rating «4»></label>
      
        <input class="star" type="radio" id="star-5" name="rating" value="5">
        <label for="star-5" title="Rating «5»"></label>
      
      </div>
      <input class="comment" type="textarea" class="text" name="text" required minLength="10">
     <button class="button">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [client-side validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) HTML attributes on the form elements to add restrictions.

### Radios

We can add the `required` attribute on the rating radios to ensure that one of them needs to be selected, as per [MDN documentation on the `required` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)

> In the case of a same named group of radio buttons, if a single radio button in the group has the `required` attribute, a radio button in that group must be checked, although it doesn't have to be the one with the attribute is applied. So to improve code maintenance, it is recommended to either include the `required` attribute in every same-named radio button in the group, or else in none.

### Comment

For the comment input (note: `textarea` is not a [valid `<input>` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#input_types), did you mean `text` or perhaps [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)?), we can again use the `required` attribute to ensure some input is entered, but this will not ensure a minimum length of 10 characters. To ensure a minimum length of characters, we can use the `minlength` attribute, for either [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#minlength) or [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-minlength).

### Result

This results in your form markup looking like this:

```html
<form class="form" action="">
    <div class="rating">
        <input required class="star" type="radio" id="star-1" name="rating" value="1">
        <label for="star-1" title="Rating «1»"></label>
      
        <input required class="star" type="radio" id="star-2" name="rating" value="2">
        <label for="star-2" title="Rating «2»"></label>
      
        <input required class="star" type="radio" id="star-3" name="rating" value="3">
        <label for="star-3" title="Rating «3»"></label>
      
        <input required class="star" type="radio" id="star-4" name="rating" value="4">
        <label for="star-4" title="Rating «4»"></label>
      
        <input required class="star" type="radio" id="star-5" name="rating" value="5">
        <label for="star-5" title="Rating «5»"></label>
      
      </div>
      <input required minlength="10" class="comment" type="text" class="text" name="text">
   <button class="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Also note, as per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#client-side_validation):

> Client-side validation is useful, but it does not guarantee that the server will receive valid data. If the data must be in a specific format, always verify it also on the server-side, and return